# I am having multiple value in 1 cell of a csv file, how to code in pandas to split the value and paste in different column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

the column is `subject` having values `"CN=account.live.com,OU=Windows Live Operations,O=Microsoft Corporation,street=One Microsoft Way,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,postalCode=98052,C=US,serialNumber=600413485,businessCategory=Private Organization,jurisdictionST=Washington,jurisdictionC=US"` in single cell.

The expected output is:

```
account.live.com in new column named as CN
Windows Live Operations in new column named as OU
Microsoft Corporation in new column named as O and so on till US in new column Jurisdiction.
```

Can some one please help me code this is python

Comment: There are different ways to do that, with regular expression, with the csv module with various pandas tools. It would be easier to provide you a good answer if you give use some more context, at least the number of rows and columns of your csv file, whether all rows contain similar values with exact same structure  and the way you currently read the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try str.split and then copy to a new column.
But more appropriate way is to use apply then regex.
I am not sure how familiar you are with this, we can go into details if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Input:

```
    subject
0   CN=account.live.com,OU=Windows Live Operations...
```

Code where `input_df` is your input:

```
new_dict = {}
def split_col(x):
    vals = x.split(",")
    for val in vals:
        col, val = val.split("=")
        if col in new_dict:
            new_dict[col].append(val)
        else:
            new_dict[col] = [val]
input_df["subject"].apply(split_col)
final_output = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
    CN                  OU                      O                       ST
0   account.live.com    Windows Live Operations Microsoft Corporation   One Microsoft Way ...
```